# how to move "div" bottom to top and top to bottom when click on same "div"

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have this jquery code

```
$("#Wrapper").click(function() {
    var th = $(this);
    if ($(th).css('top') == '-400px') {
        console.log("ret");
        $(th).animate({
            "top": "50px"
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        console.log("sdffsdsff");
        $(th).animate({
            "top": "-400px"
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

this code is workin initially but later on it slows down the speed.

what i am looking for when i click on "wrapper" it should moves to top.
when again i click on same "wrapper" it  should moves to bottom

or there is another way to scroll page up and down with "wrapper"?

how to do that? further more suggestions improving animation really appreciated .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your fiddle is a bit of a code-dump :S http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: why this question given negative remarks?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ankitgupta, see SW4's comment. You need to reduce your code in that jsFiddle to the minimal, complete, verifiable example, meaning get rid of anything that doesn't have to do with your question. This is why your post is getting downvoted.

Comment: ok i am come back again with short fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop the animation when you click and set the click handler of `Wrapper` outside of the click handler of `Article_1`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Article_1').click(function () {
        $("#Article_1").toggleClass('magictime perspectiveDown');
        $("#Article_3").toggleClass('magictime perspectiveUp'); 
    });

    $("#Wrapper").click(function () {
        var th = $(this);
        if (!th.hasClass('down')) {
            console.log("ret");
            th.addClass('down').stop(true).animate({
                "top": "50px"
            }, 1000, function() {
                $('body').scrollTop(th.height());
            });
        } else {
            console.log("sdffsdsff");
            th.removeClass('down').stop(true).animate({
                "top": "-400px"
            }, 1000, function() {
                $('body').scrollTop(th.scrollTop());
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thx for reply but it still not working properly.some other solution.ok when "div" goes to bottom on page when click on it how to scroll at bottom and top respectively.

Comment: I updated my answer in order to correct a little bug. Sorry, but I'm not sure of what you want in your comment. Can you rephrase and be more explicit please?

Comment: thx for given your valuable time.this question related to scroll when move "div" to bottom of page how to scroll page at bottom and again i click same  "div" move at top then how to scroll page at top again.this question related to scroll?

Comment: i think i should delete this post. i got 2 negative remarks can i delete this post?

Comment: You do like you want! I updated my answer to give you an idea of how to scroll. This is just an idea and I don't think it is working as expected. But you can try around that.

Comment: thanky you very much for your valuable time.this works better and i will try around it.hope u will help me again.